# Timestamps within array modification

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to get rid of / set to zero the time in the timestamp.
I can do it with the singular cell, but struggle to mimic the same logic for the whole column.

Thanks.

```
    function timestampFormat(){
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxx')
  var k = new Date(SS.getSheetByName("S1").getRange('a3').getValues());
  Logger.log(k);
  var formattedDate = new Date(k.setHours(0,0,0,0));
  Logger.log(formattedDate);
  var rn= SS.getSheetByName("S1").getRange(1,1,10).getValues();
  Logger.log(rn);
  // var formDates = [];
  // for (var i = 0; i < rn.length; i++){
  // var formDates[i] =new Date(rn.setHours(0,0,0,0));  }
  // Logger.log(formDates);
  }
```

[image: timeStamp in the array]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification? The method of `getValues` returns 2 dimensional array. So in this modification, each value is converted using `map`.

#### From:

```
var rn= SS.getSheetByName("S1").getRange(1,1,10).getValues();
```

#### To:

```
var rn = SS.getSheetByName("S1").getRange(1, 1, 10).getValues();
var res = rn.map(([a]) => [a instanceof Date ? new Date(a.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) : a]);
console.log(res)
```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Got it! Thank you!